# Is there a way to trigger google sheet script upon data insertion from contact form 7 (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 on my WordPress site to get data from user and storing user responses on a google sheet using CF7 google sheet connector plugin. I want is that whenever a new entry is added via contact form 7 on the google sheet it triggers a google sheet script's function which sorts the sheet.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a script you can use a formula.
*(In general it is NOT a good idea to mess with raw data)*

To do this just create a new sheet and use the following formula *(so as to exclude the if present headers from sorting in row `1`)*

```
=SORT('Sheet1'!A2:Z,2,1)
```

Or even

```
=QUERY('Copy of Sheet1'!A1:Z,"select * where B is not null order by B",1)
```

*Please adjust ranges to your needs*

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)